# Error while installing Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I want to install Oracle Apex 5.1.1 in my Oracle 11g database. While installing it was not properly installed so I uninstalled it. I cross checked it with dba_registry table that there is no more Oracle Apex installed. But when I tried to install it again I am getting an error that already there is an Oracle Apex installed. I crossed checked again with db_registry table but there is no Oracle Apex installed.

I am getting the error:

> 'APEX_050100' already exists.

When I checked in the dba_segments table I found there is an owner 'APEX_050100'. I don't know if this is creating issue.

I have a database connections between local and production region which is in a different virtual machine. Both are having same username and password. The production one has Oracle Apex installed. I am trying to install the Oracle Apex in my local one.

Comment: I have edited in the material from your comment. Please edit questions rather than adding extra detail in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can try running the **@apxremov.sq**l script before installation starts. This script is used to remove all currently installed versions of Oracle Apex from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle APEX will definitely work on Oracle 11. Just run `@apxremov.sql` as sysdba within APEX directory (on the server) and you'll be good to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Apex 5 will not work on Oracle 11, it only works on 12. The problem you are having is due to existing schema, possibly a failed installation. See Apex docs for "failed installation" removal step.

Comment: Not true. Apex works on Oracle 11g, also on the Oracle XE 11g version.